# matlab 'box' overlays to plot

Tags: matlab, plot

The following code

```
figure;
plot3(rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),'.')
box on
```

produces this output:

[image]

I do not like that the box lines overlay to the plot.

I would like to not show the box lines in the foreground (e.g. (0,1,1)->(0,0,1)) while still showing the other ones (e.g., (0,1,0)->(1,1,0)). Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Remove the box then? grid on maybe?

Comment: But then the lines in the background would not be continous

Comment: "continuous" ? as oposed to discrete?

Comment: as opposed to dotted like the other grid lines. (sorry for my english..)

Comment: I dont understand.... if you remove `box on` and add `grid on` what is the difference you get? you dont get "continuous" lines, then what do you get? Because I do get the lines in the background. I am using MATLAB 2014b, so you migth get different things...

Comment: I have 2014a. Also the code above differs from the example [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/box.html). It is like my default option for box is 'full'. I do not know how to modify this

Answer (score 2):

since MATLAB version R2015b you can control the Box by The `BoxStyle`-property:

```
ax = gca;
ax.BoxStyle = 'back';
```

or

```
figure;
plot3(rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),'.')
box on
set(gca, 'BoxStyle','back')
```

for older versions you can use the grid with solid line-style instead:

```
figure;
plot3(rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),rand(1,1000),'.')
grid on
set(gca,'GridLineStyle','-')
```

Comment: Thanks! 'back' looks like what I am looking for. But with 2014a I get an error message 'The name 'BoxStyle' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'axes'.

Comment: or, with the first method: *Warning: Struct field assignment overwrites a value with class "double". See
MATLAB R14SP2 Release Notes, Assigning Nonstructure Variables As Structures
Displays Warning, for details.*

Comment: I've edited the example. Maybe that is what you are expecting